# Cancel documents in the printer queue from java in windows

Tags: java, printing, queue, documents

Is it possible to cancel a print job once it has already been put into the document queue in windows with java code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you're looking for (note that I haven't tested the example myself)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/CancelablePrintJob.html

Comment: Thanks for finding this. This does seem to work to stop a print job that shows spooling in the document queue but is there a way to cancel the job once it is fully in the print queue? If I press the cancel button in that example code you posted I get: javax.print.PrintException: Job could not be cancelled.

Comment: I guess what I might be looking at is a way to control the windows print spooler rather than the print job as the print job is already finished. Or is there a way to set an auto timeout to detele the document from the print queue with a windows setting or with java code?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an easy way to stop a specific job. It will probably involve using JNI, but I haven't coded enough windows specific stuff to tell you exactly how.

However, if all you need is to *clear* the print queue, then you can possibly execute this using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

   net stop spooler
   del C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\*.* /q
   net start spooler

Comment: Voting down due to link rot, the site provided has been moved.  Editing original post.

Comment: This thread may also be of interest.  It talks about using JNA to clear a print queue: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/661#issuecomment-221025927